# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ shuts down randomly

Tags: raspbian-stretch, power-supply, pi-3b+, shutdown

My RPi 3 B+ shuts down randomly.
I have a official power supply and a 32 GB Toshiba microSDHC class 4 card.
I'm using it as a host for a Discord bot.

Comment: have to you checked any logs for any information?

Comment: Have you got a reliable power supply that gives a steady 5.1V @ 2.5A?

Comment: where to check it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your logs in /var/logs using your preferred shell commands such as

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ less /var/log/syslog
```

You can also post that file or the end of it to a file hosting site and paste the link here.

Lastly, here are is some good [raspberry pi troubleshooting information](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting)

Comment: Nothing worked.

Comment: What did you try and what is in your log files?

Answer (score 0):

As Dougie commented here, check your power supply. Not having required voltage  caused my rpi to reboot often.

Comment: I checked it. It haves required voltage.

Comment: Have you connected power hungry devices to your 5V pin or usb ports?